# I can't Create React App using 'npx create-react-app'

Tags: reactjs, node.js, npm, create-react-app, npx

I am trying to use the npx create-react app, but I have errors that are shown below:

```
npm ERR! code ENOENT
npm ERR! syscall lstat
npm ERR! path C:\Users\Administrator
npm ERR! errno -4058
npm ERR! enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, lstat 'C:\Users\Administrator'
npm ERR! enoent This is related to npm not being able to find a file.
npm ERR! enoent 

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in: C:\Users\rtyuiop\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_logs\2023-10-10T23_20_24_197Z-debug-0.log
```

And the log file of the error is here...!

```
0 verbose cli C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\bin\npm-cli.js
1 info using npm@9.8.1
2 info using node@v18.18.0
3 timing npm:load:whichnode Completed in 3ms
4 timing config:load:defaults Completed in 5ms
5 timing config:load:file:C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\npmrc Completed in 8ms
6 timing config:load:builtin Completed in 8ms
7 timing config:load:cli Completed in 2ms
8 timing config:load:env Completed in 1ms
9 timing config:load:file:D:\DEVOWFS\M204\TPs\.npmrc Completed in 0ms
10 timing config:load:project Completed in 2ms
11 timing config:load:file:C:\Users\rtyuiop\.npmrc Completed in 2ms
12 timing config:load:user Completed in 2ms
13 timing config:load:file:C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Roaming\npm\etc\npmrc Completed in 1ms
14 timing config:load:global Completed in 1ms
15 timing config:load:setEnvs Completed in 1ms
16 timing config:load Completed in 23ms
17 timing npm:load:configload Completed in 23ms
18 timing config:load:flatten Completed in 5ms
19 timing npm:load:mkdirpcache Completed in 0ms
20 timing npm:load:mkdirplogs Completed in 0ms
21 verbose title npm exec create-react-app JeuDe
22 verbose argv "exec" "--" "create-react-app" "JeuDe"
23 timing npm:load:setTitle Completed in 2ms
24 timing npm:load:display Completed in 0ms
25 verbose logfile logs-max:10 dir:C:\Users\rtyuiop\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_logs\2023-10-10T23_20_24_197Z-
26 verbose logfile C:\Users\rtyuiop\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_logs\2023-10-10T23_20_24_197Z-debug-0.log
27 timing npm:load:logFile Completed in 16ms
28 timing npm:load:timers Completed in 0ms
29 timing npm:load:configScope Completed in 0ms
30 timing npm:load Completed in 99ms
31 timing arborist:ctor Completed in 2ms
32 silly logfile start cleaning logs, removing 2 files
33 silly logfile done cleaning log files
34 http fetch GET 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/create-react-app 1260ms (cache revalidated)
35 timing arborist:ctor Completed in 0ms
36 timing command:exec Completed in 1305ms
37 verbose stack Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, lstat 'C:\Users\Administrator'
38 verbose cwd D:\DEVOWFS\M204\TPs
39 verbose Windows_NT 10.0.19045
40 verbose node v18.18.0
41 verbose npm  v9.8.1
42 error code ENOENT
43 error syscall lstat
44 error path C:\Users\Administrator
45 error errno -4058
46 error enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, lstat 'C:\Users\Administrator'
47 error enoent This is related to npm not being able to find a file.
47 error enoent
48 verbose exit -4058
49 timing npm Completed in 2157ms
50 verbose code -4058
51 error A complete log of this run can be found in: C:\Users\rtyuiop\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_logs\2023-10-10T23_20_24_197Z-debug-0.log
```

How can I resolve this issue, knowing that I used

`npm cache clean --force`, `npm install -g create-react-app@latest`, `npx create-react-app project_name --template all`, `npm init`,
`npm install create-react-app`, `npx create-react-app myapp`, `npm install -g create-react-app`

but without success.

Comment: https://dev.to/ag2byte/create-react-app-is-officially-dead-h7o

Answer (score 2):

You can do this:

```
npm i create-react-app@latest
```

then:

```
npx create-react-app my-app
```

Answer (score 0):

try First:

```
npm cache clear --force
```

then:

```
npm install -g create-react-app
```

last:

```
npx create-react-app [name_app]
```